# Issues with removeEventListener() not removing an event, testing under Chrome Externsion

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm calling the following method to set and then remove an `input` event listener on a DOM element from my Google Chrome extension's *content script*:

```
//From the global scope
gl = {
setEventIfNotDoneAlready: function(elmt)
{
    if(elmt.doneAlready)
        return true;

    if(!elmt.myEventSet)
    {
        elmt.addEventListener('input', gl.onMyInputEvent, true);

        elmt.myEventSet = true;
    }

    return false;
},

onMyInputEvent: function(elmt)
{
    elmt.target.doneAlready = true;

    elmt.target.removeEventListener('input', gl.onMyInputEvent, true);

    console.log(">>Input fired!");
}

};
```

and then the method above is called as such:

```
var objAll = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = 0; i < objAll.length; i++)
{
    if(objAll[i].isContentEditable)
    {
        if(gl.setEventIfNotDoneAlready(objAll[i]))
        {
            //And so on...
        }
    }
}
```

I need to point out that the code above is injected into arbitrary pages that the Chrome browser user navigates to. (This is done from a Chrome Extension.)

This approach seems to work fine on most pages, except in some cases the `removeEventListener` doesn't do anything and my `onMyInputEvent` continues to be called like if nothing was done.

Any idea why?

Comment: I'd double check to make sure that you aren't injecting your script into the page multiple times.

Comment: @ScottF: Well, I thought my `if(!elmt.myEventSet)` statement would prevent that, wouldn't it?

Comment: injecting again would overwrite `gl.onMyInputEvent`, so you would be trying to remove a different `gl.onMyInputEvent` from what you added as a listener. (which wouldn't work)

Comment: @ScottF: Well, what I was trying to say is that my `myEventSet` property would prevent repeated injections, wouldn't it?